# development files listed under sources in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, iis

Project: ASP.net, .net Framework 4.8

Languages: C#, JS, TS

I work on a website for my company. After a recent prod deployment, where I changed most of the sites scripts from plain JS to TypeScript, suddenly files with development urls started to appear under the sources tab in Edge developer tools.

```
website.company.com  
website-test.company.com  
website-dev.company.com
```

As far as I can see, only files from the first url are actually used and loaded. And not all files needed for the site are listed under -test and -dev. What appears there seems random, but it's only typescript-files.

We have, so far, not seen any actual issues stemming from this, but it is weird and I want to understand if it could create issues.

I checked the network protocol and web data. All good there.